# i want alert some thing every time when i pressed enter key

Tags: javascript

every time time when i pressed the enter key in input field then it should alert some thing but facing problem in doing that here is the code.

```
 <input type="text" class="searchfld" id='input' onchange="gotothatpost(this.value)" onkeyup="ajxsrch(this.value)">
```

Here is the js code

```
 <script>
 function ajxsrch(str)
 {
  var keycod;
   if(window.event)
    { 
    keycod = str.getAscii();
    }
   if(keycod==13){alert("You pressed Enter");}
  } 
  </script>
```

Comment: What is going wrong? No alert? Something else?

Comment: In your js code, ajxsech should be ajxsrch

Comment: yeah showing no alert

Comment: @trevor ignore that now

Comment: What is the `getAscii()` method?  And, why aren't you using the onkeypress method and then getting the key from the event?

Comment: @jfriend00 it is predefined function

Comment: better check by alerting the keycod value itself, before your if condition to make sure its getting proper value you want to check against..!

Comment: if i alert the keycod then it says undefined

Comment: There's no 13 going into your string in an input field so you're never going to get it from `this.value`.  If you want to see when enter was pressed, you have to respond to key events, not change events and look at the actual keycode from the key event.

Comment: @jfriend00 then how can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you aren't passing e to the function and only using window.event which does not work in all browsers. Try this code instead.

```
<input type="text" class="searchfld" id='input' onchange="gotothatpost(this.value)">

 <script>
 function ajxsrch(e)
 {
e = e||event;
  var keycod;
   if(e)
    { 
    keycod = e.keyCode||e.which;
    }
   if(keycod==13){alert("You pressed Enter");}
  } 
document.getElementById("input").onkeyup=ajxsrch;
  </script>
```

Comment: This makes no sense.  You get `e` into the event handler and then you never actually get the keycode from it.

Comment: Well, the variable name keycod is sort of misleading in this example. This person is using the function getAscii which gets the ASCII code of the last key pressed, so the way the OP is doing it is valid. It may be preferable to use e.which or e.keyCode or e.charCode etc. but for the sake of sticking as close as possible to the OP's code this works too.

Comment: What does `e` have to do with anything here and where is any documentation on `getAscii()` on a string value?

Comment: IE uses e, Firefox/Chrome use window.event . That's what e has to do with anything.
Also, my bad, the documentation I was looking at is ActionScript :S fixed now. For a while I thought I just learned a new function :P

Comment: OK, now you're actually using the keycode from the event.  Finally, this answer makes a bit of sense.  Odd that the OP accepted it when it didn't even work.

Comment: Perhaps the OP created their own implementation of getAscii and so it worked hence it was marked correctly, although that is quite strange otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<input type="text" class="searchfld" id='input' onchange="gotothatpost(this.value)" onkeyup="ajxsrch(event)">


<script>
 function ajxsrch(e)
 {
     if (e.which === 13) {
     alert("You pressed Enter");
     }
     return false;
  } 
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event object to the function call

```
<input type="text" class="searchfld" id='input' onkeyup="ajxsrch(event)">
```

Use the event object in the JS and get the key value.

```
function ajxsrch(ev) {
    var ch = ev.keyCode || ev.which || ev.charCode; // Proper way of getting the key value
    if(ch == 13) {
        alert("You pressed enter");
    }
}
```